# required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.ReactiveDiscoveryClient' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I am upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.0 . I catch error.

File `GatewayApplication.java`

```java
package org.sid.gateway;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.ReactiveDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.discovery.DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.discovery.DiscoveryLocatorProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/customers/**").uri("lb://CUSTOMER-SERVICE"))
                .route(r -> r.path("/products/**").uri("lb://INVENTORY-SERVICE"))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator dynamicRoutes(ReactiveDiscoveryClient rdc, DiscoveryLocatorProperties dlp) {
        return new DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator(rdc, dlp);
    }

}
```

```java
Parameter 0 of method dynamicRoutes in org.sid.gateway.GatewayApplication required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.ReactiveDiscoveryClient' that could not be found.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: by making sure that that class can be autowired (is it component/service/...) and that it's on the path at compile- and runtime

Comment: My full source code https://github.com/donhuvy/micro-service-usecase/blob/777d068ae198b9f4507cc4d2b1594622829d4b92/gateway/src/main/java/org/sid/gateway/GatewayApplication.java#L27 @Stultuske please specific and more detail.

Comment: the implementations (I know of) of that interface are in spring-cloud-commons. Try adding a dependency tot that: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons/3.1.5

Comment: You are using Spring Cloud, Spring Cloud is tied to certain versions of Spring Boot. You are using incmopatible versions. For Spring Boot you need 2022.0.x (release train) anything else is for Spring Boot 2.x releases.

Comment: Are you sure `2022.x` , I think latest version of Spring Cloud is still `2021.x` ?

Comment: `2022.x` is the one compatible with Boot 3.0.0. However, it's not GA yet. The release is planned for mid-December; if you're using Spring Cloud in your apps, we suggest you wait till then with doing the switch to Boot 3.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your application properties

```
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=true
```